# O que significa o erro "value used here after move" em Rust?

Tags: rust

Eu estou estudando Rust e gostaria de entender melhor quando posso e quando não posso usar uma mesma variável mais de uma vez em um mesmo escopo.

Deixo abaixo dois exemplos.

No primeiro, o programa funciona como o esperado, mas no segundo, que faz a mesma coisa, deparo-me com o erro *value used here after move*. Veja:

```
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let text = "Whatever your hand finds to do, do it with all your might, for in the realm of the dead, where you are going, there is neither working nor planning nor knowledge nor wisdom.";
    let re = Regex::new(r"\b(m|d)[a-z]+").unwrap();
    let captures = re.find_iter(text);
    for cap in captures {
        let begin = cap.start() - 10;
        let fim = cap.end() + 10;
        println!("{}", &text[begin..fim])
    }
}
```

Funciona corretamente. Sem nenhum erro.

Por outro lado, o programa a seguir:

```
use fancy_regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let text = "Whatever your hand finds to do, do it with all your might, for in the realm of the dead, where you are going, there is neither working nor planning nor knowledge nor wisdom.";
    let re = Regex::new(r"\b(m|d)[a-z]+").unwrap();
    let captures = re.find_iter(text);
    for cap in captures {
        let begin = cap.unwrap().start() - 10;
        let fim = cap.unwrap().end() + 10;
        println!("{}", &text[begin..fim])
    }
}
```

Retorna o erro:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `cap`
   --> src/main.rs:9:19
    |
7   |     for cap in captures {
    |         --- move occurs because `cap` has type `std::result::Result<fancy_regex::Match<'_>, fancy_regex::Error>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
8   |         let begin = cap.unwrap().start() - 10;
    |                         -------- `cap` moved due to this method call
9   |         let fim = cap.unwrap().end() + 10;
    |                   ^^^ value used here after move
```

Minha pergunta é: por que no primeiro caso eu posso usar a variável `cap` duas vezes e no segundo não? O que significa o erro *value used here after move*?

<sup>Eu estou deliberadamente usando dois módulos diferentes para ilustrar o problema.</sup>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rust é uma linguagem extremamente diferente das demais *mainstream*, e esse fator diferencial é justamente do que trata esta pergunta. Embora um pouco "estranho", esse fator também é visto como um dos pontos mais fortes do Rust. Por conta dessa *sui generi*, é impossível redigir uma resposta totalmente detalhada, já que teria de se explicar, integralmente, como o modelo de *ownership* funciona em Rust.

Portanto, para um pleno entendimento, é ideal ler, na íntegra, o capítulo [*Understanding Ownership*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html), do livro oficial da linguagem.

Dito isso, um certo resumo não fará mal.

---

O sistema de *ownership* em Rust é regido sobre [três regras](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#ownership-rules):

1. Cada valor em Rust tem *uma* variável associada. Essa variável é chamada de *dona* de seu valor.
2. Cada valor pode possuir somente *um* dono. <kbd>**Atenção**</kbd>
3. Quando a variável (dona de um valor) sai do escopo de um bloco, o valor será liberado.

Vamos nos atentar ao segundo item acima. Embora um valor possa possuir somente um dono em um dado momento, não existe impedimento para que se *transfira* o *ownership* desse valor. Ou seja, é possível *transferir* a posse (*ownership*) do valor de uma variável para outra. Esse tipo de ação chama-se ***move*** (*the ownership*).

Por exemplo:

```
// A variável `s1` é dona da String:
let s1 = String::from("hello");

// A String foi movida da variável `s1`.
// A partir de agora, a variável `s2` é a dona.
let s2 = s1;
```

Nesse sentido, podemos reproduzir um erro similar ao da pergunta ao tentar acessar o valor da variável `s1` após ter sido movido para `s2`. Se tentássemos fazer isto:

```
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("hello");
    let s2 = s1;

    println!("{}, world!", s1);
}
```

O compilador lançaria um erro similar a este:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `s1`
 --> src/main.rs:5:28
  |
2 |     let s1 = String::from("hello");
  |         -- move occurs because `s1` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
3 |     let s2 = s1;
  |              -- value moved here
4 | 
5 |     println!("{}, world!", s1);
  |                            ^^ value borrowed here after move
```

Isso basicamente significa que tentamos acessar o valor de uma variável que não é mais dona dele. Obviamente, como postula a regra 2 (um valor somente pode possuir um dono), isso seria razão para erro. Se o valor teve sua **posse** alterada entre variáveis, é de se esperar que a *antiga dona* não seja mais válida – o que justifica o erro.

Desse modo, entendemos que não podemos utilizar uma variável cujo valor foi *movido* para tentar *acessar* um valor.

---

Mas o valor <s>não</s> foi movido no código da pergunta... Ou foi? *(...)*

Retomando o código *problemático* do AP:

> ```
> use fancy_regex::Regex;
>
> fn main() {
>     let text = "...";
>     let re = Regex::new(r"\b(m|d)[a-z]+").unwrap();
>     let captures = re.find_iter(text);
>     for cap in captures {
>         let begin = cap.unwrap().start() - 10;
>         let fim = cap.unwrap().end() + 10;
>         println!("{}", &text[begin..fim]);
>     }
> }
> ```

É possível perceber (pela mensagem de erro da pergunta) que o erro se dá tento em vista que o valor da variável `cap` está tentando ser acessado **após ter sido *movido***.

Na situação em questão, `cap` é do tipo `std::result::Result<Match, Error>`. Vejamos agora a assinatura do método [`unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap):

```
pub fn unwrap(self) -> T
```

Note que o valor `self` está sendo *utilizado* de modo a *tomar* o *ownership* da instância. Isso significa que ocorrerá uma modificação de *ownership* implícita. Preste atenção no `self` – se fosse `&self` ou `&mut self`, a história seria outra; mas não trataremos disso aqui para não estender muito.

Ou seja, o método `unwrap` de `Result`s tomam para si a posse do valor, que é "totalmente consumido". Isso significa que a variável que continha o `Result` não poderá mais ser "lida", haja vista que o valor teve sua posse alterada. Pense que a posse foi para uma variável dentro do método `unwrap` (essa variável é o parâmetro `self`).

Portanto, para corrigir isso, basta chamar `unwrap` somente uma vez, de modo que a variável não é mais acessada posteriormente:

```
let re_match = cap.unwrap();
let begin = re_match.start() - 10;
let fim = re_match.end() + 10;
// ...
```

<sup>Note que agora a variável `cap`, única para cada iteração do `for`, não é mais utilizada após a posse de seu valor ter sido movida para o parâmetro `self` do método `unwrap`.</sup>

De acordo com o capítulo 5.3, *[[Struct] Method Syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html)*:

> Having a method that takes ownership of the instance by using just `self` as the first parameter is rare; this technique is usually used when the method transforms `self` into something else and you want to prevent the caller from using the original instance after the transformation.

Isto é, um método que pega o *ownership* da instância (utilizando `self` como primeiro argumento) é raro. Essa técnica é geralmente utilizada quando o método transforma `self` em outra coisa e há o desejo de prevenir o chamador de usar a instância original após a transformação.

E essa necessidade faz sentido no caso do `unwrap`, de modo que o *ownership* da instância do `Result` é tomada após chamar o método em questão.

---

Novamente, insisto que a leitura dos capítulos mencionados nesta resposta são de suma importância para que *realmente* se entenda como o sistema de *ownership* funciona em Rust. O que falei aqui é apenas um resumo. Não mencionei sequer nada sobre *borrowing*, que também é importante nessa matéria.

Comment: sei que não devo usar o comentário para isso, mas parabéns pela resposta!