# Toda struct definida pelo usuário está alocada no heap?

Tags: rust

Achei esse exemplo no *The Book* um pouco curioso:

```
struct Rectangle {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let rect1 = Rectangle {
        width: 30,
        height: 50,
    };

    println!(
        "The area of the rectangle is {} square pixels.",
        area(&rect1)
    );
}

fn area(rectangle: &Rectangle) -> u32 {
    rectangle.width * rectangle.height
}
```

É necessário passar o argumento na função `area` como uma *reference*? A `struct` *Rectangle*  é composto por *fields* que são de um tipo primitivo e, portanto, alocados na *stack*, então imaginava que as instâncias de *Rectangle* também estariam alocado na *stack*, tornando o *borrowing* redundante aqui.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você está tratando referências como um mecanismo que faz alocação na *heap*. Esse não é o caso. Você pode utilizar uma referência para emprestar um valor que está na *stack*. É isso que ocorre no seu exemplo.

Referências em Rust têm um comportamento semântico definido: elas são um mecanismo de emprestar um valor cuja posse é de outra variável. O fato de estar armazenado na *stack* ou na *heap* não depende da referência em si, mas sim de onde o *owned value* está armazenado. Se esse *owned value* estiver na *stack*, então a referência aponta à *stack*; se o valor estiver na *heap*, a referência aponta à *heap*.

Estruturas não são criadas na *heap*. Todo *struct* é inicialmente criado na *stack*. Todavia você pode, após essa “instanciação”, mover a estrutura para a *heap* utilizando um [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html) (que é o mecanismo mais idiomático de alocar um valor na *heap*). Também não há alocação na *heap* quando se empresta (*borrow* – isto é, cria uma referência) uma estrutura ou qualquer outro valor.

O `Box` é basicamente um *smart pointer* que detém a posse (*is the owner of*) do valor com o qual foi criado. Ele irá armazenar esse valor na *heap* e será capaz, pelos mecanismos de derreferenciação, de ser utilizado normalmente como uma referência. Nesse caso a referência certamente aponta à *heap*. Exempo:

```
struct Rectangle {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
}

fn main() {
  // É criado na stack. O valor `my_rect` está na stack.
  let my_rect = Rectangle { width: 1, height: 2 };

  // Movemos o valor `my_rect` para a função `new`.
  // Internamente agora `my_rect` estará armazenado na heap.
  //
  // O `boxed_rect` é um Box<Rectangle>. O Box é capaz de dereferenciar
  // para a estrutura que agora encontra-se na heap.
  let boxed_rect = Box::new(my_rect);
}
```

Mas o `Box` não é o foco desta pergunta, então vou linkar ao [livro para uma explicação mais detalhada](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-01-box.html). E sobre a [semântica de derreferenciação](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html).

Como já foi dito, por padrão, quando se cria um novo *struct*, a alocação ocorre na *stack*. **O fato de uma função aceitar uma *referência* a uma estrutura não significa que ela apontará a algum valor que está na *heap*.**

A referência, em Rust, é um conceito que faz parte das semânticas de *borrowing* e *ownership*. Não é porque você *empresta* (cria uma referência) algum valor que ele necessariamente estará na *heap*. O conceito de “referência” existe para que você possa acessar algum valor sem necessariamente ter a sua posse.

Como já vimos, o fato de você ter uma referência não faz com que o valor seja obrigatoriamente alocado na *heap*. Você escolhe quando quer alocar algo na *heap* (geralmente utilizando `Box`). Acho que isso já responde a pergunta.

---

Só para finalizar:

> É necessário passar o argumento na função `area` como uma *reference*?

Não, mas nesse caso me parece o mais ideal a ser feito.

Repare que você só quer ler os campos. Não realiza sequer modificações através da referência. Esse é um caso ideal para utilizar uma *shared reference* como você fez.

Se você fosse modificar o valor, deveria utilizar uma *mutable reference*, que exige unicidade.

Uma outra opção, nesse caso menos ideal, é simplesmente obter a posse do valor, assim:

```
fn area(rectangle: Rectangle) -> u32 {
    rectangle.width * rectangle.height
}
```

O problema é que, uma vez que a função fosse chamada, o valor que anteriormente estava no escopo da função chamadora não estará mais lá. Ele  foi movido. Isso significa que não poderá ser mais usado lá. Nesse caso você teria que “devolver” a posse do valor, retornando, da função, o `Rectangle`. Isso é bastante improdutivo, né? Tanto é que existe o conceito de *borrow*. Nesse caso, você utiliza referências para somente “pegar o valor emprestado“, sem ter que obter a posse dele.

Essa mesma problematização que usei anteriormente é feita no final do capítulo 4.1, que introduz o *ownership*, e solucionada no capítulo 4.2 com a introdução do conceito de *borrowing*.

Se ficou pouco claro, sugiro veementemente ler o [capítulo 4](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html), na íntegra, para mais bem compreender o exemplo anterior.

E claro que há casos onde aceitar a posse do valor é mais semanticamente indicado. Um exemplo é o método `Result::unwrap`, que *consome* o `Result`, de modo que não é mais possível utilizá-lo após a execução do método, que retorna o valor dentro da variante `Ok` no caso de sucesso. Isso já foi tratado nesta outra [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/503445/69296).

Comment: Acho rust muito louco por alocar tudo na stack por padrão, diferente de C#, JS, etc... Isso não traz problemas já que a stack é mais limitada?

Comment: Em que sentido a stack seria mais limitada, @Francisco? A não ser que você aloque _muita_ coisa na stack (de modo a ter um stack overflow), não há nenhum problema em armazenar valores ali. Evidentemente, isso só é possível quando o compilador consegue determinar o tamanho dos tipos (o que é o caso). De fato, ajuda até com a performance do programa, já que evita alocações na heap desnecessariamente.